# Two ways of determining if object has property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Given this object:

```
var myObject = {
    ...
};
```

Is this method:

```
var hasProp = Object.keys(myObject).indexOf('myProp') !== -1;
```

The same as:

```
var hasProp = myObject.hasOwnProperty('myProp')
```

That is, will they result in the same value for `hasProp`, always?

I was asked this in an interview and the interviewer said they would yield different results but did not give me an example.

Thanks!

Comment: I think they should be equivalent. They both ignore keys inherited from prototypes.

Comment: The only difference I can think of, is that `.hasOwnProperty` can be overridden, so it is safer to do `{}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)`

Comment: A summary from the answers below: Both can be used to check the existence of ***own properties***. The difference is `Object.keys` can just be used for ***enumerable*** own properties while `hasOwnProperty` can **also** be used for ***non-enumerable*** properties. So the case when they differ is when checking against ***non-enumerable own properties***.

Answer (score 5):

Any **non-enumerable property** breaks this symmetry. For example, fire up a Node.js console or use a compliant browser's console to perform both:

```
Object.keys([]);             // yields []
[].hasOwnProperty('length'); // yields true.
```

because for arrays, the magic `length` property is marked as non-enumerable. There is another function which does all of them, even non-enumerables:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames([]) // yields [ 'length' ]
```

that is fully equivalent.

Answer (score 3):

[`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) "returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties". `hasOwnProperty` works regardless of the fact that the property is enumerable or not.

See this example where `hasOwnProperty` is true yet `Object.keys` does not contain the property.

```
var obj = {};
Object.defineProperty(obj, "prop", {value: 1, enumerable: false});
obj.prop; // 1

obj.hasOwnProperty("prop"); // true
Object.keys(obj); // []
Object.keys(obj).indexOf('prop'); // -1
```

This uses the ECMAScript 5 [`defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) but non-enumerable properties also exist on basic objects. As shown by @ChrisDrost, the array's `length` is a non-enumerable property that does not show up in `Object.keys` yet responds true to `hasOwnProperty`.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will not always return the same value for `hasOwnProperty`.

From [Mozilla's Documentation on hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

> Example: Direct versus inherited properties
>
> The following example differentiates between direct properties and
>   properties inherited through the prototype chain:
>
> ```
> o = new Object(); o.prop = 'exists'; o.hasOwnProperty('prop'); // returns true      
> o.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // returns false
> o.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty');   // returns false
> ```

Which means that your method acts as a sort of `hasOwnProperty` that also checks for inherited attributes.

I think in practice, they act the same, but this a subtle difference.

Comment: `Object.keys()` doesn't read inherited properties. It performs a *HasOwnProperty* check.